# Nativescript 5.1 Core JS TabView in a Sidedrawer page not working

Tags: navigation-drawer, nativescript, tabview

I have created a nativescript application under NS core JS 4, i don't remember the
exact minor version, sorry. 
Because of some great improvements I updated my app to V5.1 of NS core with JS.

Here my tns version...

```
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-core-modules has 5.1.1 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-android has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
√ Component tns-ios has 5.1.0 version and is up to date.
```

After that, my app stopped working.
The App has a side drawer with a menu and every time i want to navigate from a
page with a TabView in it, the application crashes...

```
System.err: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0xffffffec
System.err:     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceTypeName(Resources.java:3271)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:1172)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1543)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
ActivityManager: Process org.nativescript.myappname (pid 4063)(adj 0) has died(67,647)
```

I don't have a playground to show the problem but it's reproducible...

Created a fresh app with the side drawer template.

```
tns create testapp --template tns-template-drawer-navigation
```

Start this app.

```
tns run android
```

Navigate around a bit and see the app is working. Let's say you navigate to "browse" in the side drawer. And then navigate to "home"...It works.

Edit the app and, to use our example from above, change "browse-page.xml". 
Replace the GridLayout with...

```
<TabView>
 <TabViewItem title="first tab">
  <Label text="short test text on tab 1" />
 </TabViewItem>
 <TabViewItem title="second tab">
  <Label text="short test text on tab 2" />
 </TabViewItem>
</TabView>
```

Now try again. Navigate around in the App. Navigate to any menu entry you want.
But if you are in "browse" and try to navigate to another menu entry, the app
will crash with the above error message.
The TabView itself is working.

I tried to wrap the TabView in a StackLayout and a GridLayout...does not help.

Is somebody else having the same problem or can somebody help me to fix that
issue?

thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

I created a playground. Its a little stripped down and the problem does not
exist there.

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=tvDeOz

I also uploaded my testapp here..

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fqMDDbjLdN6YK670c3qawUU_Xfect1xm

**EDIT 2**

So, i played around a bit...installed node, android sdk, java and ns completely new.
When I create an app as described above and run it in preview mode, everything is ok.
When I run the app on my android device or an emulator, the error described above is thrown.
My test phone is on Android 5.0.1. The emulator is v7.0.

So I'm a little bit clueless.

best regards
ingo

Comment: Is it possible for you to setup a Playground or share a repo where we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I try to make a playground. Perhaps the problem will not happen there.

Comment: playground and google links added to question..

Comment: Unfortunately if the issue couldn't be reproduced, I doubt we could check any further.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps something is wrong with my node, NS or android studio installation. I try on a fresh maschine. sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: Make sure the dependency versions in Playground matches with your project.